# Check if current time come in between two NSDate (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm making a simple app which retrieves information about nearby restaurants. I get all the data from an external web service. Each restaurant object has a `NSDictionary` which contains the working hours of that particular restaurant. This `NSDictionary` is structured like so..

```
"restaurant_working_hours" =         (
                    {
            close =                 {
                day = 1;
                dayName = Monday;
                time = 0000;
            };
            open =                 {
                day = 1;
                dayName = Monday;
                time = 1500;
            };
        },
                    {
            close =                 {
                day = 2;
                dayName = Tuesday;
                time = 0000;
            };
            open =                 {
                day = 2;
                dayName = Tuesday;
                time = 1500;
            };
        },
                    {
            close =                 {
                day = 3;
                dayName = Wednesday;
                time = 0000;
            };
            open =                 {
                day = 3;
                dayName = Wednesday;
                time = 1500;
            };
        },
                    {
            close =                 {
                day = 4;
                dayName = Thursday;
                time = 0000;
            };
            open =                 {
                day = 4;
                dayName = Thursday;
                time = 1500;
            };
        },
                    {
            close =                 {
                day = 5;
                dayName = Friday;
                time = 0000;
            };
            open =                 {
                day = 5;
                dayName = Friday;
                time = 1500;
            };
        }
    );
```

In my app I need an option to find out if the restaurant is open or closed now. And also the working hours of that day in 12hr format.

I'm relatively new to development and have no idea how to approach this. I could simply run it in a loop and get all the dates but that seems inefficient.

Thank you :)

Comment: Check that link first.If you get the answer please close

Comment: Seems like you have to convert it to `NSDate` first

Comment: ok I agree your word , can you show your tried code

Comment: In the link provided by @Droppy there is just two `NSDate` so its very straight forward. In my case I have the closing and opening time from all seven days of the week. So that seems a bit tricky for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `NSDate` to do the comparison.  You need to:

1. Get the current date/time (as `NSDate`) and extract the current time in seconds from midnight.
2. Convert that time from the dictionaries into seconds from midnight.  It's in a strange format and I am assuming, for example, that `1326` would be "26 minutes past 1PM".

1:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                                      fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger nowSeconds = ([comps hour] * 60 * 24) + ([comps minutes] * 60) + [comps seconds];
```

2:

```
+ (NSInteger)dictTimeToSeconds:(NSInteger)dictTime
{
    NSInteger hours = dictTime / 100;
    NSInteger minutes = dictTime % 100;
    return (hours * 60 * 24) + (minutes * 60);
}

...

NSArray *workingHours = thatDictionary[@"restaurant_working_hours"];
for (NSDictionary *days in workingHours) {
    NSInteger openTime = [self dictTimeToSeconds:days[@"open"][@"time"]];
    NSInteger closeTime = [self dictTimeToSeconds:days[@"close"][@"time"]];
    if (openTime < nowSeconds && closeTime > nowSeconds) {
        NSLog(@"Open on day %@", days[@"open"][@"dayName"]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Closed on day %@", days[@"open"][@"dayName"]);
    }
}
```

Note: the structure of the server data is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I agree. But I can't change the structure. I get the data from google's Places API.

Comment: Yes. It works. But with a bit of alterations though. I'l post what I did in the answers. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Droppy..this is exactly what I did in my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]

NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"close.dayName like '%@'",dayName];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *result = [restaurantWorkingHoursDict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSMutableDictionary *todayDict = [result firstObject];

NSString *closeString = [[todayDict objectForKey:@"close"] objectForKey:@"time"];
NSString *openString = [[todayDict objectForKey:@"open"] objectForKey:@"time"];

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmm"];

NSDate *openDate = [outputFormatter dateFromString:openString];
NSDate *closeDate = [outputFormatter dateFromString:closeString];

[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

NSString *openingHour = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:openDate];
NSString *closingHour = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:closeDate];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                                      fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger nowSeconds = ([comps hour] * 60 * 60) + ([comps minute] * 60) + [comps second];

NSInteger closeSecond = [self dictTimeToSeconds:[closeString integerValue]];
NSInteger openSecond = [self dictTimeToSeconds:[openString integerValue]];

if (openSecond < nowSeconds && closeSecond > nowSeconds) {
    self.openLebal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open Now from:%@ till:%@",openingHour,closingHour];
} else {
    self.openLebal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Closed Now. Open from:%@ till:%@",openingHour,closingHour];
}

....

- (NSInteger)dictTimeToSeconds:(NSInteger)dictTime{
    NSInteger hours = dictTime / 100;
    NSInteger minutes = dictTime % 100;
    return (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60);
}
```

Made a few alterations. Hope this will help someone else.